# Excel VBA JSON Conversion

Tags: json, excel, vba

JSON Excerpt -

```json
[
    {"id": "c3a8cb7365ea45e27100d868c382b0f6", 
     "sport_key": "icehockey_sweden_allsvenskan", 
     "sport_title": "HockeyAllsvenskan", 
     "commence_time": "2023-03-19T17:00:00Z", 
     "home_team": "V\u00e4sterviks IK", 
     "away_team": "Tingsryds AIF", 
     "bookmakers": [
        {...
```

Result -

Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Code -

```vb
Dim responses As Object 
Set responses = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.ResponseText) 'responses = Replace(responses, Chr(34), Chr(39))

' Access the data Debug.Print request.ResponseText Debug.Print responses("id")

Dim responses As Object
Set responses = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.ResponseText)
'responses = Replace(responses, Chr(34), Chr(39))

' Access the data

Debug.Print request.ResponseText
Debug.Print responses("id")  <<< Line throwing error :(
```

Had a thought that converter is looking for `'` instead of `"` ...????

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `Debug.Print responses(1)("id")`. Either `'` or `"` is ok in json. `responses.Count` will give you the upper index,

Comment: `responses` is a `Collection` - each item in the Collection is a `Dictionary`  Basically when using VBA JSON, `[]` becomes a Collection, `{}` becomes a Dictionary